# How to get ID value of parents of previous and next carousel slides? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, carousel

I am trying to write script that will assign description to carousel's "prev" and "next" links. Descriptions need to be read from carousel item ID attribute based on numeric value of current slide (that can be accessed via carousel API - see first line of JS code - returns numeric value of carousel item starting from 1)

HTML:

```
<div id="carousel-wrapper" class="content-promo carousel-wrapper>
  <div class='wrapper'>

    <div id='features' class=' ccm-block-styles'>
      <div id='slide-1' class='carousel-slide'>
         <!-- SOME CONTENT  -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id='lifestyle' class=' ccm-block-styles'>
      <div id='slide-2' class='carousel-slide'>
         <!-- SOME CONTENT  -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id='food-&-drink' class=' ccm-block-styles'>
      <div id='slide-3' class='carousel-slide'>
         <!-- SOME CONTENT  -->
      </div>
    </div>

  </div> <!-- End of .wrapper -->
</div> <!-- End of #carousel-wrapper -->
```

JS:

```
currentslide = $( ".carousel-wrapper" ).rcarousel( "getCurrentPage" );
prevslide = currentslide - 2; // as eq() counts from 0
prevslideidtext = $(".carousel-slide").eq( prevslide ).parent().attr( "id" );
nextslide = currentslide;
nextslideidtext = $(".carousel-slide").eq( nextslide ).parent().attr( "id" );
```

Unfortunately `prevslideidtext` instead of returning ID of previous slide parent DIV returns ID of current slide parent when `nextslideidtext`is `undefined`.

Example of results (when first slide is current slide):

```
currentslide = 1
prevslide = -1
nextslide = 1
prevslideidtext = features
nextslideidtext = undefined
```

There are six DIVs with `carousel-slide` class (only 3 are shown in HTML code above) but JS script above behaves as there was only one.

What I am doing wrong?

I don't insist on using `eq();`it just seemed to me to be clear and easy way to achieve effect I need.

(I am aware that eq() creates new empty item when index passed to eq() is out of range, I was going to sort it out - for last slide - later)

Thanks

Comment: So if its the first slide.. should prev be the last?  and if last slide.. should next be the first?

Comment: Yes, that's looped carousel. and that's the reason for my choice of `eq()` as `eg(-1)` means _"first from the end"_. For the last slide I was going to sort it out comparing `nextslide` value with total number of slides and in case of last slide just read ID of first slide parent. However my problem is different - JS code above doesn't work as supposed - I can't get values of prev and next slide ID.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround I found for my problem:

```
// 1. Read and save old carousel navigation text (like "Prev" and "Next")
carouselprevoldtext = $('#ui-carousel-prev').children(".carousel-control-text").html();
carouselnextoldtext = $('#ui-carousel-next').children(".carousel-control-text").html();
// 2. How many slides?
maxslidenumber = $(".carousel-slide").length;
// 3. Create an array with all slides' IDs (in this particular case I use parent() as ID is assigned through CMS by user not hardcoded - and extra DIV is added by CMS)
slideidarray = {};
$(".carousel-slide").each(
    function(index){
    slideidarray[index] = $ ( this ).parent().attr('id');
}                      
);
// 4. Run the carousel
$( ".carousel-wrapper" ).rcarousel({ OPTIONS HERE });
// 5. Find current slide
currentslide = $( ".carousel-wrapper" ).rcarousel( "getCurrentPage" ); // starts from 1 not from 0
// 6. Find previous and next slides ID texts
// A. For first slide - previous slide is the last one
if (currentslide == 1) {
    prevslideidtext = slideidarray[maxslidenumber - 1];
    nextslideidtext = slideidarray[1];
}
else {
    prevslideidtext = slideidarray[currentslide - 2]; // as arrays count from 0
    nextslideidtext = slideidarray[currentslide];
    // B. For last slide - next slide is the first one
    if (currentslide == maxslidenumber) {
    nextslideidtext = slideidarray[0];
    }
}
// 7. Create new carousel navigation text
carouselprevupdhtml = "<span class='carousel-control-text'>" + carouselprevoldtext + ": </span><span class='carousel-control-title'>" + prevslideidtext + '</span>';
carouselnextupdhtml = "<span class='carousel-control-text'>" + carouselnextoldtext + ": </span><span class='carousel-control-title'>" + nextslideidtext + '</span>';
// 8. Assign it to carousel navigation
$('#ui-carousel-prev').html( carouselprevupdhtml );
$('#ui-carousel-next').html( carouselnextupdhtml );
```

Of course steps 5 to 8 needs to be repeated each time when slide is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi well first for me to help you better can you do the following:

1.) Place your sample code in JSFiddle or CodePen. Then post that link back here.
http://jsfiddle.net/
http://codepen.io/

Just a tip I would recommend that you change the classname or the ID name you have above. It's not good practice to have both an ID and a class with the same name.

You have the following:

```
<div id="carousel-wrapper" class="content-promo carousel-wrapper>
```

---

Update: Appears you need to close the quote from the class attribute for the #carousel-wrapper element.

Comment: OK, done, here's the link: [jsfiddle.net/SCbtk/3/] I changed two things: 1. value of `currentslide` is hardcoded (so code shown is independent on the rest of script) 2. second slide is now the current one so it's simpler situation as there's no issue with "next" link for last slide

Comment: Let's step through this... http://jsfiddle.net/SCbtk/4/   All I did was close quote from #carousel-wrapper class.  Was that your only issue?

Comment: Unfortunately lack of closing quote was only typo in fiddle. This quote DOES exist in my code. However you let me understand that I was wrong that this isolated code shown in the fiddle was the source of the problem and is independen from the rest of the script. You're right the code shown in the fiddle works as expected. That, together with the results from real (whole)  script takes me to conclusion that `eq()` deals with list of `.carousel-item` that contains ONE item only.

Comment: Apparently carousel plugin I am using somehow removes all slides but current one from DOM tree (and this is actually visible in page source).  So I am assuming that what I need to do is 1. before I run carousel I need to read all required IDs and store them in array, 2. run carousel, 3. check current slide number, 4. read ID of previous and next slide from array, 5, apply to carousel controls with `html();`As I am really beginner in jQuery my first question is _"Is this proper approach?"_ and my second question: _"What's the best way to do first step (to store ID values into array)?"_

Comment: I think the issue is more of how you are using the plugin. I did a search for that plugin and found an example page. View the pages source code both in Firebug and by right clicking on the page and clicking 'View Source'. You'll get some helpful tips. (http://ryrych.github.com/rcarousel/examples/html.html)

Comment: I know this website, that's where I took the plugin from. You may be right and I will check this. I only used simple carousel call `$( ".carousel-wrapper" ).rcarousel({ OPTIONS HERE });` not `generatePages()` or `pageLoaded()` functions as carousel worked without them (other examples don't use them either).

Comment: I posted my workaround here, but I will try to modify the way how I run the carousel to check it makes any difference. Thanks for your help!